# How to get previous and next posts in codeigniter blog post page

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, blogs

I'm making a blog in Codeigniter. Now on the blog post view page, I want the previous and next post link. This is my controller of blog details.

```
    public function blog_details($slug = NULL){
    //data
    $data['blog_info'] = $this->Blog_model->get_posts($slug);
    if(empty($data['blog_info'])){
        show_404();
    }
    
    $data['post_name'] = $data['blog_info']['post_name'];//post name
    $data['categories'] = $this->Blog_model->get_categories();
    //meta title, discription, keywords
    $data['meta_title'] = $data['blog_info']['post_name'];
    $data['meta_description'] = $data['blog_info']['post_meta'];
    $data['meta_keywords'] = $data['blog_info']['post_tags'];
    //view
    $data['main_content'] = 'blog_details';
    $this->load->view('include/template',$data);
}
```

and my model is

```
   public function get_posts($slug = FALSE, $limit = TRUE, $offset = FALSE){
        if($limit){
            $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
        }
        if($slug === FALSE){
            $this->db->order_by('blogs.post_id', 'DESC');
            $this->db->join('category', 'category.category_name = blogs.category');
            $query = $this->db->get('blogs');
            return $query->result_array();
        }
    
        $query = $this->db->get_where('blogs', array('post_slug' => $slug));
        return $query->row_array();
    }
```

How to create previous and next post links with post names? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If limit and offset are boolean type values, then how can you expect the limit clause to work?  `empty()` is inappropriate when a variable is guaranteed to exist.

Answer (score 0):

you can use direct query method to run below query and just pass your blog id to get previus and next blog name

```html
public function get_prewnext($id){
    $query =  $this->db->query("SELECT name,
       (SELECT name FROM blog s1
        WHERE s1.id < s.id
        ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) as previous_name,
       (SELECT name FROM blog s2
        WHERE s2.id > s.id
        ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1) as next_name
FROM blog s
    WHERE id = $id;");
    
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
            $data =  $query->result_array();
        }
        $query->free_result();
       
        return $data;
 }
```

Note: If value is not found then it will return null.

Comment: This query is not using best practices.  Variables should not be injected directly into the sql when a placeholder is appropriate.  Freeing the result is unnecessary, as well as checking the num_rows.